# Consulta a varios modelos Django

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo estos modelos:

```
class TablaA(models.Model):
    estado = models.BooleanField()
    # mas campos...

class TablaB(models.Model):
    tabla_a = models.ForeignKey(TablaA)
    estado = models.BooleanField()
    # mas campos...

class TablaC(models.Model):
    tabla_a = models.ForeignKey(TablaA)
    # mas campos...
```

Lo que necesito es tener los datos de `TablaC` cuando los campos `estado` de `TablaA` y de `TablaB` sean `False`.

¿Cómo es posible hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

ps podrias hacerlo asi..

```
from yourapp import models
a = models.TablaA
b = models.TablaB
c = models.TablaC
if a.estado == False and b.estado == False:
  return c.tabla_a
```

Puedes retornar c.tabla_a o cualquiero otro dato que este en la tabla.

Me comentas como te va

saludos

Comment: Algo parecido había hecho al inicio, sin embargo buscaba reducir las consultas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví usando `select_related()` y `FOO_set`.

```
data = TablaB.objects.filter(tabla_a__Estado=False)
```

Y en el template al momento de recorrer:

```
{% for d in data %}
    data.tabla_c.tablaa_set.all
    {{ data.foo.bar }}
{% endfor %}
```

Tomando en cuenta que en TablaB hay también una referencia a TablaC.

Sin embargo ahora, en otra sección de la aplicación, necesito hacerlo en una sola consulta para en el template solamente recorrer y ya no hacer una consulta adicional. Aún no logro hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @Christian. ¡Gracias por compartir la respuesta! Sería genial si pudieses poner algo más de detalle, cuestión de que le sea útil a alguien que tiene tu mismo problema. Me imagino que publicar el código final aportaría un excelente ejemplo.

Comment: Igual que @Mariano sugiero ampliar un poco mas la respuesta